# Jekyll - getting an error when I have Paginate in my project

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, pagination

I'm running 3.1.2 on Windows

When I try to add 'Paginate' to my project, I'm getting an error in cmd

> Deprecation: You appear to have pagination turned on, but you haven't
>   included the `jekyll-paginate` gem. Ensure you have `gems:
>   [jekyll-paginate]` in your configuration file.

I have `jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)` and `paginate (4.0.0)` installed and it's still giving this error.

Here is my _config.yml file:

```
paginate: 4
paginate_path: '/blog/page:num/'
```

And my index.html page

```
{% for post in paginator.posts limit: 4 %}
```

What should I check, to resolve this?

Comment: Ensure you have `gems:  [jekyll-paginate]` in your configuration file aka `_config.yml`

Comment: Thank you David!  Now it works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jekyll guys have removed Paginate plugin from version 3.x as it did not play nicely with more core features. You can still enable it using any of these three options

1. In your site source root, make a `_plugins` directory. Place your plugins here. Any file ending in *.rb inside this directory will be loaded before Jekyll generates your site.
2. In your `_config.yml` file, add a new array with the key gems and the values of the gem names of the plugins you’d like to use. An example:

`gems: [jekyll-coffeescript, jekyll-watch, jekyll-assets]
    # This will require each of these gems automatically.`

Then install your plugins using `gem install jekyll-paginate-category jekyll-watch jekyll-assets`

3. Add the relevant plugins to a Bundler group in your Gemfile. An example:

    `group :jekyll_plugins do
      gem "my-jekyll-plugin"
      gem "jekyll-paginate-category"
    end`

   Now you need to install all plugins from your Bundler group by running single command `bundle install`

You can find more information on jekyll [plugins page](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/)

Comment: Thank you @AntK I already added gems: [jekyll-paginate] to my _config file and everything looks fine..

Comment: I noticed the comment, it's good for stats to have the questions answered on this site since this is where people mostly land from google, so if it's not to much trouble can you mark my answer as correct as I tried to give a detailed answer for people who will land here in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the issue is that you have 2 versions of Jekyll, one installed through "apt" and another thru "gem". Try to remove the one installed with "apt" (or whatever command you're using) and update the other version using the bundler "bundle update". I have this error I've corrected by removing Jekyll I installed by "apt" command. 
** Notes: I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following in your `_config.yml` file.

`gems: [jekyll-paginate]`

Comment: The 'gems' configuration option has been renamed to 'plugins'. It should now be `plugins: [jekyll-paginate]`